# How can I fix error in Travis CI in gcc C++ compiler?

Tags: c++, travis-ci

I'm developing a class for working with texts in C++ (training project). I connected a Travis CI to my git repository to test the code. First build broke with such an error:

```
The command "if [ $TRAVIS_OS_NAME == linux ]; then sudo apt-get install -y llvm-3.4 llvm-3.4-dev; fi" failed and exited with 100 during .
```

Could someone please explain to me for what caused this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should actually read the full output that Travis gives you:

```
E: Unable to locate package llvm-3.4

E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'llvm-3.4'

E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'llvm-3.4'

E: Unable to locate package llvm-3.4-dev

E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'llvm-3.4-dev'

E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'llvm-3.4-dev'

The command "if [ $TRAVIS_OS_NAME == linux ]; then sudo apt-get install -y llvm-3.4 llvm-3.4-dev; fi" failed and exited with 100 during .
```

The packages `llvm-3.4` and `llvm-3.4-dev` are simply not available in the repository. If you check the build system information, you will see:

```
Operating System Details

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

Release:    16.04

Codename:   xenial
```

You can try to find out wich llvm packages are available in Ubuntu 16.04 by an online search. Alternatively, you can add `apt-cache search --names-only llvm` as the first command in the `before_install` section of your `.travis.yml` to get a list of available llvm packages. The run will still fail until you replace the version numbers with one from the list.

Comment: I added this to my .travis.yml file, but after that Travis stopped parsing commits. Not sure why this could happen?

Comment: Maybe my sentence was a little bit unclear. Corrected it. I meant that `apt-cache search --names-only llvm` should be the first command executed in the shell. Therefore it needs to be the first item in the `before_install` section and not in the file itself ;)

Comment: I did this, but the build still crashed. Instead of llvm-3.4 I have to select some other available library from the list, right? I mean the list that appeared thanks to 
```apt-cache search --names-only llvm```

Comment: Correct. I checked the list and version 3.5 should already work.

Comment: Writes that some files are missing in the directory ```/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/rubygems-update-2.7.8```
And where is this directory and how to add the necessary files to it?

Comment: I am currently not at home anymore. Until tomorrow, I can't take a look and help you. Try to google the error messages. Maybe you find something related. Otherwise, ask a new question with the new error here on stackoverflow, since the original one is already solved. Good luck. I ll check your repo status tomorrow.

Comment: Took a look into your repository. Seems like you solved, the Travis related problems. The current error is caused by your c++ build system. (no makefile). The second command `./Text/Text/ttext.cpp`, which also fails, does not make sense. You are trying to execute a `.cpp` file, which is just source code. You should make sure that your program actually builds on your computer, before building on Travis. From browsing through your repo I guess you are developing in Windows. You should first learn how you build cpp programs in Linux.

Comment: I suggest that you replace all your commands in the `script` section of your `.travis.yml` by a simple `echo Hello`. This should result in a successful Travis run. Then continue adding additional commands one by one and solve any error that occurs, before adding another command. If you don't know how and can't find any useful information on the internet, ask another Stackoverflow question about the error you can't solve.